# AngularJS with nested ngShow are delayed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an angular js project and noticed that if I nest my ng-show's they are delayed.  In the example below I would expect to not ever see the "BBB" text but I do.  What I see is "AAA", then if the button is clicked, the more() function is called and $scope.model.loading is set to true.  The button text shows "BBB" although the button it self should now be hidden then after a moment the button hides.

```
<button class="button" ng-click="more()" ng-show="!model.loading">
    <span ng-show="!model.loading">AAA</span>
    <span ng-show="model.loading">BBB</span>
</button>
```

Why is it delayed and how can I fix it?

Comment: a demo that replicates problem would likely help

Comment: If your model.loading is set to true, the entire button and it's contents will be hidden. I've created a plunkr with your exact scenario and it works as expected. http://plnkr.co/edit/Luh0L8u91tk1ur4DQ2Iw?p=preview

Comment: Wow, thanks for building that plunkr.  You're right, in the plunkr it's working as expected.  I'm not sure what's going on in my code.  My code is obviously more complicated than the example... I'm not sure how to proceed.  I'm using the iconic framework and also doing a $http request so maybe the code is getting held up somewhere.  Thanks for the help.